# Is “actual” both a false friend and a cognate from Spanish to English?

Tags: meaning, etymology, spanish

English definition of “actual”:

*existing in fact; typically as contrasted with what was intended, expected, or believed.*

Spanish definition of “actual”:

*current, present, contemporary*

These are clearly false friends and many ESL resources list “actual” as a false friend with Romance language “actual.”

However, English is polysemic and “actual” can also mean

*existing now; current*

For example — Projected income exceeded actual (current) income.

Is this a case of actual being a cognate and false friend between English and Spanish?

Comment: It's a false friend. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/actual) marks the definition *now existing; current* as **now rare** and **from 18th c.** If you use *actual* and intend this definition, very few people today will understand you.

Comment: If it is a false cognate, though still a cognate, isn't it actually a false friend?  I think you've answered your own question through your research, which is encouraged!  Please do write an answer in the answer box.

Comment: Does "actual income" really mean "current income", rather than something vaguer and context-dependent like "income for which the most recent figures are available"? Citations, please.

Comment: I would read "actual income" as real in-fact income, rather than some projection or adjusted figure.  So you could talk about actual income for 2022 and 2021 and 2020 without it having to be income "now".